Why form request not getting sent when using jQuery submit() method in Firefox (works ok in Chrome)?
Hi following is a portion of HTML on a webpage:
<form id="sitemap_diff" action="/sitemaps/generate_sitemap_diff" method="get">
  // more HTML elements here
  <button class="btn btn-success cls" id="cls" type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>

And the following event handler (in the same erb file):
  $('.cls').click(function () {
    $('#sitemap_diff').submit();
    // more code
  });

On click of button, the handler is executed (confirmed via log).
But the request is not being sent when on Firefox (v 113.0.2) on Ubuntu.
But on Chrome the request is getting sent.
We are using jQuery version 1.10.2.
Is there a reason why the submit() method does not work in Firefox browser ?

The // more code won't run. Submitting the form reloads the page and the rest of the code is cancelled.

Any other errors in your dev-tools Console? Try enabling the "Preserve log" option so you can see messages across navigation events.

Hi @Barmar i added log after the submit() call. I can see that it got printed.

Hi @Phil no errors but 2 warnings i can see: 1) Cookie “downloadStarted” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value 2) Empty string passed to getElementById(). Can these be related to the problem ?

@NishantKumar try: $('.cls').click(function (e) {     e.preventDefault(); $('#sitemap_diff').submit();   }); . Also it's a GET method so empty form posting has no impact.

@Death-is-the-real-truth It's not an empty form, there's a comment saying there are other elements in the form, presumably inputs that are irrelevant to the question.

Why do you need to call submit() explicitly? The form will be submitted automatically by default when the handler returns, unless it calls e.preventDefault().
